# Queuing processing and Gamma distribution

Tags: probability, queueing-theory, gamma-distribution

I've been trying to solve the following exercise and I was hoping for your input.

> If $Q$ is a queueing process with arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$, and a customer arrives to find exactly $k$ customers waiting ahead (including the person being served), show that this customer leaves the queueing system after a length of time which has the gamma distribution with parameters $k+1$ and $\mu$.
>
> *source: Probability: An Introduction - Grimmet & Welsh*

If we call $Z$ the random variable that is equal to the time that $k+1$ customers have been dealt with, we know that $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}X_i$ with $X_i$ being the service time for customer $i$. We know that $X_i$ for all $i$ is distributed exponentially with parameter $\mu$. That is: $\forall i\in \{ 1,2,\ldots ,k+1\}: X_i \sim Exp(\mu)$.
Thus I assume that we need to find that a sum of $b$ exponentially distributed random variables, all with parameter $a$ is Gamma distributed with parameters $a$ and $b$ respectively.

How could I show this in a neat manner? I'd assume using convolution integrals combined with induction, but I feel as if there should be an easier/smarter way of showing this fact.

Thanks for your time

K. Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the easiest way is with moment generating functions. These are often useful when dealing with sums of iid random variables.

First, note that $\Gamma(1,\mu) = \mathcal E(\mu)$, ie an exponential with rate $\mu$.
Now our claim is that $\Gamma(\ell,\mu) + \Gamma(k,\mu) = \Gamma(\ell+k,\mu)$, in distribution, where the two random variables on the left-hand side are independent -- write these two as $X_\ell$ and $X_k$.
Using the pdf for the $\Gamma$ distribution, one can calculate that
$$ E(e^{\theta X_k}) = (1 - \theta/\mu)^{-k} \quad\text{for}\quad \theta < \mu. $$
Hence we see that
$$ E(e^{\theta(X_k + X_\ell)}) = E(e^{\theta X_k}) E(e^{\theta X_\ell}) = (1 - \theta/\mu)^{-(k+\ell)}, $$
which is the mgf of $\Gamma(k+\ell,\mu)$.

A simply application of induction now implies that $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathcal E_i \sim \Gamma(n,\mu)$ if $\mathcal E_i \sim \mathcal E(\mu)$.